# jquery pre-load image from php script then display

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preload

I've searched around for this case and came close but I'm having a problem finishing it off.

I've got a PHP script that creates a graph. It does so by creating a png img then using the header to display the image to the page.

I can do something like:

```
$('#img').attr('src', 'url.php?make_graph=1');
```

And this works. The problem is, I have some graphs that take quite a while to create, upwards of a minute and while that is happening the image is just blank and the webpage looks like it's doing nothing.

I've found a way to pre-load the image but not a way to apply it to the webpage (from stack overflow actually). I can do:

```
$('<img/>', {
    'src': 'url.php....',
    'load': function(){ alert("loaded!"); }
});
```

So my question is, can I load the image in a manner like this and apply it to an existing image on the page somehow? I'm not sure if that sentence is very clear.... I'm missing the piece where I can actually display a preloaded image made from a script. I'd like to avoid saving the image or using iframes if possible.

Tanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Once loaded, set the image src to the same location that you loaded behind the scenes and it will (in theory) get pulled from the cache and displayed to the user.

```
$("<img>", {
    "src": "url.php...",
    "load": function() {
        alert("loaded!");
        $("#foo").attr("src", "url.php...");
    }
});​
```

Here is an example I put together. It initially loads one image on the page, then loads a different image behind the scenes. When you confirm the alert message, it will then swap the images by changing the src. I confirmed that it pulls the image from the cache using the Chrome dev tools.
http://jsfiddle.net/uVFLD/1/

There may be another way to solve this problem, but that was the first solution that came to mind.